# Using chrome.storage.get to get a variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a little Chrome extension and I have successfully used the options page to use chrome.storage.sync.set to set the variable pws. However, on the pop-up page I cannot successfully retrieve the variable and use it in the string. Here is the code where it goes:

```
weather.open("GET", "http://api.wunderground.com/api/"+WU_API_KEY+"/conditions/q/CA/pws:"+pws+".json", true);
weather.send()

})
```

How do I get pws in there as a variable from chrome.sync.storage.get?

I tried something like

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(pws, function(result){

var pws = result.pws
console.debug('result:',pws);

});
```

but no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `"pws"` as a key to store `pws`, then you could:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("pws", function(result) {
    var pws = result.pws;
    console.log("result:", pws);
});
```